# Recovering unsaved word file

Tags: microsoft-word, clipboard

I pasted a long text in the word and the source was gone so I can't copy it again. And in a rush while closing word I forgot to hit save and wrongly clicked on don't save option. Now I have no idea if I can recover it in anyway? I copied something else in meanwhile so I can't paste it again. I tried to look for clipboard history but nothing. I am using windows 7 pro. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard history is not saved by default. There are many third party software options that do track clipboard history and I would recommend using them for the future. Obviously that doesn't help you now. The answer is the one you don't want to hear but Windows 7 does not save clipboard history.

If it was a word document, you can try opening it again to see if the auto recovery feature brings your information back in. If not then I am sorry but your copied text is gone.

Comment: I gave it a try autorecovery didn't work. Sad I lost but I equipped with a tool to track clipboard for next. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Tab No problem. I use a program now because I did something similar to what you just did before. Please mark this as an accepted answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Offices saves 'recovery' files every few minutes starting with tilde (~) in several places... see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files .  The actual recovery doesn't always recover the file, but you may be able to open those tilde files with Notepad and get the info you need.  Check these directories for Windows 7 : "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Word"
"C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp"